# Synonyme de "frapper" ("ce qui me frappera dans cet événement c'est...")

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Connaissez-vous d'autres synonymes que ceux-là ?

> - Ce qui me sautera aux yeux c'est...
> - ...me surprendra...
> - ...me marquera...

Comment: Bienvenu sur FLSE ! Pouvez vous donner plus de détail sur l'évènement qui "sautera aux yeux", afin de trouver des synonymes au plus proche du contexte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En général on n'utilise pas *sauter aux yeux* au futur, car il y a un effet de surprise sous-entendu... qui n'existe plus si l'on est prévenu à l'avance !

Il y a des transpositions possibles, le choix dépend du contexte, des conséquences de *ce qui sautera aux yeux* :

> - Ce qui m'interpellera, c'est ...
> - L'évidence sera ...
> - Ce qui sera flagrant/sûr/visible, est ...
> - Ce qui remplira tout l'espace, c'est ...

Registre familier :

> - De tout ce que je verrai, ce qui me titillera, c'est ...
> - Ce qui m'en bouchera un coin, c'est ...
> - (Quand je le verrai,) ce qui me sciera/m'affolera/me réjouira, c'est ...

Comment: Super, merci beaucoup !